# Can you disable JS using an http header?

Tags: javascript, http, https, http-headers, content-security-policy

I am trying to disable JS on my website using
HTTP headers, currently using CSP and have
made checks fail on purpose:

```
Content-Security-Policy = "upgrade-insecure-requests; sandbox; script-src 'sha512-v'; object-src 'none';"
```

Mainly the sha512 stuff, but also other stuff helps too like sandbox

Any way to actually cleanly disable JS using http headers or am I stuck with this?

I tried `none` as script-src value, but it just threw me a warning that it's ignoring it, any other way?

Comment: `'none'` seems to work in Chrome and Firefox. What browser said it was ignoring it? Also relevant: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3230.

Comment: @ZachB Firefox was ignoring it, thanks for the reply, the issue seems to be related too, thanks, I will set it to none, though firefox ignores it and throws a warning ;(